# Windows 8 fails to perform "Offline" chkdsk scan during boot

Tags: windows-8, chkdsk

`chkdsk` won't run during boot on my Win8 (Pro RTM 64-bit, from MSDN) laptop even though I've requested it using `chkdsk /f C:` and `fsutil dirty set C:`.

In my event log, I get the following events which may be relevant (Why does Event Viewer copy them in display order instead of chronological order?  Beware the timestamps):

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager
Date:          1/28/2013 4:33:15 PM
Event ID:      6
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      redacted
Description:
File System Filter 'npsvctrig' (6.2, ‎2012‎-‎07‎-‎25T20:27:33.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager" Guid="{F3C5E28E-63F6-49C7-A204-E48A1BC4B09D}" />
    <EventID>6</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-28T22:33:15.063347500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>290913</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>redacted</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />  that's SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="FinalStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMajor">6</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMinor">2</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNameLength">9</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">npsvctrig</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceTime">2012-07-25T20:27:33.000000000Z</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager
Date:          1/28/2013 4:33:12 PM
Event ID:      6
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      redacted
Description:
File System Filter 'eamonm' (6.0, ‎2012‎-‎03‎-‎07T08:32:36.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager" Guid="{F3C5E28E-63F6-49C7-A204-E48A1BC4B09D}" />
    <EventID>6</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-28T22:33:12.426919700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>290912</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>redacted</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="FinalStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMajor">6</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMinor">0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNameLength">6</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">eamonm</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceTime">2012-03-07T08:32:36.000000000Z</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs
Date:          1/28/2013 4:33:12 PM
Event ID:      98
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      (2)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      redacted
Description:
Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume2) needs to be taken offline to perform a Full Chkdsk.  Please run "CHKDSK /F" locally via the command line, or run "REPAIR-VOLUME <drive:>" locally or remotely via PowerShell.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs" Guid="{3FF37A1C-A68D-4D6E-8C9B-F79E8B16C482}" />
    <EventID>98</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-28T22:33:12.036916400Z" />
    <EventRecordID>290911</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="44" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>redacted</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DriveName">C:</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\HarddiskVolume2</Data>
    <Data Name="CorruptionActionState">3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager
Date:          1/28/2013 4:33:11 PM
Event ID:      6
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      redacted
Description:
File System Filter 'FileInfo' (6.2, ‎2012‎-‎07‎-‎25T20:28:02.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager" Guid="{F3C5E28E-63F6-49C7-A204-E48A1BC4B09D}" />
    <EventID>6</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-28T22:33:11.272509200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>290910</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>redacted</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="FinalStatus">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMajor">6</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceVersionMinor">2</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceNameLength">8</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceName">FileInfo</Data>
    <Data Name="DeviceTime">2012-07-25T20:28:02.000000000Z</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Google suggests that file system drivers can interfere with the exclusive lock `autochk` needs to perform an offline scan, but `FileInfo` appears to be Microsoft-provided and perfectly normal.  Two other filters, `luavf` and `PSI` load much later during boot.

Any guidance on how to get `chkdsk` to scan this (the system partition) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 includes a Recovery Environment (WinRE) with a Command Prompt that loads to a RAM Disk and runs without locking the system partition, so `chkdsk /f` runs fine from there.  It's available in Windows 8 from the "Advanced Startup Options" (type `startup` at the Start screen and look in the Settings category).

If the "Command Prompt" option doesn't appear, see [Windows 8 Advanced Recovery Options are missing](https://superuser.com/q/543109/29943)

Note that WinRE won't use the Trusted Platform Module to unlock a Bitlocker-encrypted drive, so you should use "Manage BitLocker" to suspend it for a single boot.  After you perform the repairs and reboot you'll be protected again.